# Find the probability that 1 of the 2 pieces of raw linguine is longer than 12 inches.

Tags: probability

A raw linguine is fifteen inches long. I throw the raw linguine on the table and it breaks into 2 pieces. Find the probability that 1 of the 2 pieces of raw linguine is longer than 12 inches.

Would the probability be $\frac{2}{15}$

Since if the linguine breaks, it can be 13 inch, 14 inch which is 2 choices?

Comment: the break might come near either end (and i don't suppose it has to come at an integral number of inches from the end).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like homework, so here's just a hint:

As the comments point out, there is no reason to think that it can only break at the inch marks. A more realistic model would be that the break point is uniformly distributed from 0 to 15. In this case, there are two ways you can get a piece at least 12 inches. Let $p$ be the point where the break occurs:

$$P(p<3 \;\;\text{or} \;\;p>12)$$

Can you take it from there?